# Wrap template classes with different template argument

Tags: c++, delegates, threadpool

I want to write a thread pool and in thread pool i have queues of tasks.
each task is a delegate with different result types.

I want to insert this delegates in thread pool queues, but because each delegate has different template argument this is not possible.

I want an approach that will wrap this delegates with different template argument, so that i can insert them in queue.

Function of thread pool that will get task:

```
Queue<Delegate<?()>> workQueue; // Can't use specific type

template<typename R>
Task<R> doWork(Delegate<R(void)> del)
{
    workQueue.pushBack(del); // Can't do this
}
```

Or something like this pseudo code:

```
Array{ Delegate<void(void)>, Delegate<int(void)>, Delegate<MyClass(void)> }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Boost Any
 boost::any

Comment: I don't have boost, and i don't want use it now

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution:

```
class FunctionWrapper
{
private:

protected:
    class ImpBase
    {
    public:
        virtual ~ImpBase() {}
        virtual void call() abstract;
    };

    template<typename F>
    class Imp : public ImpBase
    {
    public:
        typename F FunctionType;

        FunctionType mFunc;

        Imp(FunctionType&& pFunc) : mFunc(std::move(pFunc)) {}
        ~Imp() {}

        void call() override { mFunc(); }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<ImpBase> mPtr;

public:
    FunctionWrapper() = default;
    FunctionWrapper(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
    template<typename F>
    FunctionWrapper(F&& pFunc) : mPtr(new Imp<F>(std::move(pFunc))) {}

    FunctionWrapper& operator =(const FunctionWrapper&) = delete;
    FunctionWrapper& operator =(FunctionWrapper&& pOther) { mPtr = std::move(pOther.mPtr); }

    void operator ()() { mPtr->call(); }
};
```